# How do i convert this input into an acceptable date

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table in mysql with a record_id and a field of type date. How can I convert the following query so that it works on inserting.. it seems the date input is not recognized.

```
insert into test_table (record_id,date_test) values ('1','21-JUN-42')
```

I would appreciate any help or explanation.

PS: date_test is of type date.

Thank you

Comment: record_id is auto increment primary key ?

Comment: i dont have issues with the primary key, its the date field i need to be able to cast that field to convert it to a valid date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do conversion before insertion

```
insert into test_table (record_id,date_test) values ('1', STR_TO_DATE('21-JUN-12', '%e-%M-%y'))
```

Comment: this works good but its putting the year as 2012 while it needs to be 1912 for example

Comment: Then you should have your year string with 4 digits format. And change the date formatter to '%e-%M-%Y'

Comment: For 1912 you need to give in 21-JUN-1912 format. and use STR_TO_DATE('Your date string', "%e-%M-%Y"); Other wist it will take current century by default. if your all records on 19.. then you can do something manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert a date field you have to do this in the format `(YYYY-MM-DD).`

No need to put value of record_id if it is `auto increment` .

use date_format to change date in required format like

```
 date_format('Your date string',"%Y-%m-%d")
```

OR

```
 STR_TO_DATE('Your date string', "%e-%M-%Y")
```

Comment: I cant arrange it the application is sending it like that.. is there a cast or something i can use to convert it to that format?

Comment: For 1912 you need to give in 21-JUN-1912 format. and use STR_TO_DATE('Your date string', "%e-%M-%Y");  Other wist it will take  current century by default. if your all records on 19.. then you can do something manually.

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the date into [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8601) format:

```
insert into test_table (record_id, date_test) values (1, '1942-06-21')
```

I also dropped the quotes on the `record_id` value, you shouldn't quote numbers even if MySQL will let you get away with it.

Comment: I cant arrange it the application is sending it like that.. is there a cast or something i can use to convert it to that format?